# Python Searching from a Wordlist Function Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-3.7

For one reason or another I am having issues with understanding how to get my word list to search a text file for the list of words I have provided. I did find a way around creating a word list by using "elif" statements but I would like to do this properly. - Python 3.7.x

```
name = 'Foo'
name1 = 'Bar'
name2 = 'python'
searchfile = open("test.txt","r")
num_lines = 0

for line in searchfile:
    num_lines += 1
    line = line.lower()
    if name in line:
        print ("Found on Line:",num_lines, line)
    elif name1 in line:
        print ("Found on Line:",num_lines, line)
    elif name2 in line:
        print ("Found on Line:",num_lines, line)
```

I would like to make the "name" variables have a lists of words to search. like so.. But I am getting errors.

```
name = ("foo","bar","python")
name1 = ("foo1","bar1","python1")
name2 = ("foo2","bar2","python2")
```

TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple
maybe if I see the correct code my brain will understand it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, it is generally considered poor practice to have numbered variables instead of a list. So rather than name='x', name1 = 'y', name2 = 'z', you instead do names = ['x', 'y', 'z']. As far as the list of names go, do you need one or all of the values in each tuple present in order to have a match? Do they need to be in order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in your example `name` is a tuple and making `name in line` would try to check if a tuple is inside the line which is string type.
You can iterate over any word you want to check like this

```
name = ('Foo', 'Bar', 'python')
searchfile = open("test.txt","r")

for num_lines, line in enumerate(searchfile, 1):
    for word in names:
        if word.lower() in line.lower():
             print("Found on Line:", num_lines, line)
```

In addition if you want to have multiple "names" as you said, you could do:

```
name = ("foo","bar","python")
name1 = ("foo1","bar1","python1")
name2 = ("foo2","bar2","python2")
names = name + name1 + name2
```

And iterate `for word in names` as before. I do not know what are your requirements, but it's better to create

```
names = ("foo", "bar", "python", "foo1", "bar1", "python1", "foo2", "bar2", "python2")
```

as a single tuple instead of N tuples.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to just use a for loop

```
name = ("foo","bar","python")
for n in name:
    if n in line:
        print ("Found on Line:",num_lines, line)
```